# PHP search with letter

Tags: php, html, database

I'm a beginner in php and I need some help.
I have this assignment for school where i need to have the alphabet in a site for a hospital and all the consultations need to appear when the letter they start with is clicked.

I only tried it with the letter 'a' but i doesn't work. I'm convinced this is really easy but I've been searching online for a while and can't find anything.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. my native language clearly isn't english.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE></TITLE>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
    <p><a href="" name="searchCons">A </a>
    <a href="">B </a><a href="">C </a><a href="D"></a>
    <a href="">D </a><a href="">E </a><a href="">F </a>
    <a href="">G </a><a href="">H </a><a href="">I </a>
    <a href="">J </a><a href="">K </a><a href="">L </a>
    <a href="">M </a><a href="">N </a><a href="">O </a>
    <a href="">P </a><a href="">Q </a><a href="">R </a>
    <a href="">S </a><a href="">T </a><a href="">U </a>
    <a href="">V </a><a href="">W </a><a href="">X </a>
    <a href="">Y </a><a href="">Z </a><a href="">Everything</a></p>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['toon']))
    {
      include('dbconnect.php');

      if(!empty($_POST['searchCons']))
      {
        $type  = $_POST['searchCons'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM consultaties WHERE Naam LIKE '%A%'";
        $res   = mysql_query($query,$cn) or die('Uitvoeren query mislukt');
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        while($rij=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        echo $rij['Naam']."<BR>";    
       } 

      mysql_close($cn);
    }

    ?>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you need a form to POST the data to the server. Or you use can AJAX as well.

Comment: Ajax might be a bit of an overkill for this purpose, I guess. OP would need do deal with Javascript which might be confusing if he just started developing dynamic websites

Comment: `or die('Uitvoeren query mislukt')` doesn't help you if you have errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your links like that:

```
<a href="?searchCons=A">A</a>
```

And instead of using POST, use GET:

```
$_GET['searchCons']
```

Where you now would assign a variable to the GET array and use it in your query:

```
$search = $_GET['searchCons'];
```

and in your query:

```
WHERE Naam LIKE '%$search%'";
```

However, this leaves you open to an SQL injection. So, you need to escape that data.

I.e.:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchCons']);
```

---

Sidenote question: What does `$_POST['toon']` do? You can remove that `if` statement if I understand your code correctly.

Comment: thank for the advice, but it still doesn't work. Should it work with your corrections?

Comment: Did you remove the line with `toon`?

Comment: yes I did, do I need to change anything else? (sorry for wasting your time)

Comment: What happens? Error message or simply a blank page?

Comment: i don't get any output at all, only the last of the php code (it was there before i clicked on the 'a') https://gyazo.com/624d3e2271c36d9f50b143ff1092bb0c

Comment: @DreamsInHD That ^ means you need to run as PHP on a webserver with PHP and MySQL installed. You're probably using `c:///file.php` in your browser as opposed to `http://localhost/file.php`.

Comment: Oh, do you use apache to view the page? Looks like you just double-clicked the file. // It might also help to add brackets (`{`, `}`) after `while`. It's a bit confusing to read without them.

Comment: but wampserver is running, and i tried some other things and they work so that souldn't be the problem.

Comment: It's not enough to have it running. Your php file must be placed in the htdocs folder and you need to access the file using `http://localhost/...` like @Fred-ii- wrote

Comment: yes i dragged the file in chrome, but it worked in the past

Comment: Yes, dragging is just the same as double-clicking. That will not execute the php code. Double-clicking is fine for normal websites but as soon as there is php, this does not work anymore

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm extremely new to this. Could you tell me how I can properly run the file?

Comment: Oh, that's too much for the comments section... Just [send me an email](http://www.bytehamster.com/?q=Contact) and we can maybe skype or whatever... (btw, I'm German too)

Comment: @DreamsInHD Wamp creates a folder called `www` during the default installation. You need to put that file in that folder and with a `.php` extension. You then paste `http://localhost/file.php` as an example in your web browser. No need to add `www`, Wamp knows what to do with it already.

Comment: @DreamsInHD hehe, I take it we have "success"! - You're welcome ;-)

Comment: @ByteHamster i completely forgot i had to put it in the www folder, sorry for wasting your time and thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Nice and short explanation. I thought it would take more text :D // DreamsInHD: Great that you had success :)

Comment: @ByteHamster *"Short & Sweet"* is the way to go, *cheers* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay ill do that. i'm pretty embarrassed to say it still doesn't work. I still get the code output but not the ouput it should give :(

Comment: @DreamsInHD Look at the comment I left under your question about checking for errors. Also use `var_dump();` to see what populates or not. It also accepts an argument. I.e.: `var_dump($var);` and view your HTML source, it's another developer's "tool". as is "echo".

Comment: @DreamsInHD I suspect that once you do check for errors, that it will throw you something about a "deprecation" notice, to use mysqli or PDO. Plus, you may get undefined index notices etc.

Comment: okay i did that this time. This is what i get: https://gyazo.com/da9300bf399942da90aedb977b74e167 (haven't clicked anything at the time the screenshot was taken). I don't think it's supposed to be commented out.

Comment: The php code is still not being executed. When trying to parse the php tag, your browser replaces it with a comment because it does not know how to execute php. Looks like the wamp server is still not set up correctly @Fred-ii- Looks like your comment was not enough after all :D

Comment: @ByteHamster do you happen to know why? Because it's logo is green. (again so sorry for wasting you time on these stupid questions)

Comment: @DreamsInHD is that file indeed a `.php` extension or `.html`? If `.html`, then you need to rename it to `.php`. If you're still seeing as code, then that doesn't make much sense right now, IF... your file extension is `.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes it is a .php file

Comment: @Fred-ii- We made it. There was indeed a "deprecation" notice, so it took some time to change everything

Comment: @ByteHamster Thanks for the update. I'm glad to hear that everything worked out, *cheers*.

Answer (score 1):

POST works with a form. Since you are not using any form in your code you should use GET. GET also works with forms but there is a way to overcome that since the GET sends the data in the link.

So you should change your links to:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

(change the `#` to `filename.php?searchCons=A`)

so your code should look to similar to this:

```
<?php


      include('dbconnect.php');

      if(!empty($_GET['searchCons']))
      {
        $type  = $_GET['searchCons'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM consultaties WHERE Naam LIKE '%A%'";
        $res   = mysql_query($query,$cn) or die('Uitvoeren query mislukt');
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        while($rij=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        echo $rij['Naam']."<BR>";    
       } 

      mysql_close($cn);


    ?>


<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>

      <a href="?searchCons=A" >A </a>
      <a href="?searchCons=B">B </a>
      <a href="?searchCons=C">C </a>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `if(!empty($_GET['searchCons']))` and you're using `$type  = $_POST['searchCons'];` which will fail. That should read as `$type  = $_GET['searchCons'];`

Answer (score 0):

check the below links that may help you
[http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/)

[check the link](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/)

Comment: Link-only answers are not a good practice here on Stack Overflow. If the linked page changes or goes offline, the answer might lose its info. Please quote the most relevant parts of the page instead of just linking it. Thanks ;) Anyway, I think Ajax might confuse the OP too much - simple html is better in this case, I guess